# juju deploy fails with "lookup store.juju.ubuntu.com: no such host"

Tags: networking, juju, maas, kvm-virtualization

I have a MAAS setup (using KVM) with 1 MAAS controller and 1 server node. I could "juju bootstrap" successfully and following is the output of "juju status"

```
vishal@maas:~$ juju status
environment: maas
machines:
  "0":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.20.11.1
    dns-name: node1.maas
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-6fb5c5d8-8c56-11e4-a114-5254005f3d68/
    series: trusty
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=4 mem=4096M tags=virtual
    state-server-member-status: has-vote
services: {}
```

I could then login into "node1" and do "sudo apt-get install nmap" without any issues i.e. apt-get could resolve the repository urls without any problem and install nmap.

However when I do "juju deploy wordpress" on the MAAS controller, it fails with the following error

```
ERROR cannot download charm "cs:trusty/wordpress-1": Cannot access the charm store. Are you connected to the internet? Error details: Get https://store.juju.ubuntu.com/charm-info?charms=cs%3Atrusty%2Fwordpress-1: dial tcp: lookup store.juju.ubuntu.com: no such host
```

My questions why is the host resolution failing on the server node if the apt-get command succeeds? Do I need to add additional dns server information somewhere so that the server node is able to resolve the URL?

Answer (score 1):

apt-get on the maas nodes is configured to use a proxy that is installed on the maas host itself. In this case, it's the maas host that performs dns resolution, and not the node. This seems to indicate that your maas server can resolve names without issues, but not your nodes.

Try this on the bootstrap node ("juju ssh 0" to get to it):

```
dig store.juju.ubuntu.com
```

Take note of its `/etc/resolv.conf`, see if it's correct.

Also check `/var/log/syslog` on the maas server and look for entries belonging to the DNS server (bind), it might be refusing your queries for some reason.